# How can I customize JSON result from my SQL query

Tags: json, sql-server

I have a couple of SQL tables that I'm trying to write a SQL query to return in JSON format.
The tables are below:

**UOM**

| Volume | Temperature | Level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Gallons | Fahrenheit | Inches |

**Location**

| State | City |
| --- | --- |
| California | Sacramento |
| Florida | Miami |
| Colorado | Denver |

I have this query:

The query I have tried below is giving me this result instead:

```
SELECT UOM.Volume AS UOM.Volume, UOM.Temperature AS UOM.Temperature, UOM.Level AS UOM.Level
    , State AS Location.State, City AS Location.City
FROM Location,UOM 
FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
```

I'm trying to return the JSON result below:

```
{
  "UOM": {
    "Volume": "Gallons",
    "Temperature": "Fahrenheit",
    "Level": "Inches"
  },
  "Location": [
    {
      "State": "California",
      "City": "Sacramento"
    },
    {
      "State": "Florida",
      "City": "Miami"
    }.
    {
      "State": "Colorado",
      "City": "Denver"
    }
  ]
}
```

But I get this instead:

```
{
  "UOM": {
    "Volume": "Gallons",
    "Temperature": "Fahrenheit",
    "Level": "Inches"
  },
  "Location": [
    {
      "State": "GP",
      "City": "GP"
    }
  ]
}


{
  "UOM": {
    "Volume": "Gallons",
    "Temperature": "Fahrenheit",
    "Level": "Inches"
  },
  "Location": [
    {
      "State": "California",
      "City": "Sacramento"
    }
  ]
}

{
  "UOM": {
    "Volume": "Gallons",
    "Temperature": "Fahrenheit",
    "Level": "Inches"
  },
  "Location": [
    {
      "State": "Florida",
      "City": "Miami"
    }
  ]
}

{
  "UOM": {
    "Volume": "Gallons",
    "Temperature": "Fahrenheit",
    "Level": "Inches"
  },
  "Location": [
    {
      "State": "Colorado",
      "City": "Denver"
    }
  ]
}
```

Anything I'm missing here?

Comment: You'll typically do MUCH better converting the result to JSON in your client code or reporting tool.  Also, the `A,B` join syntax has been obsolete for **30 years (!)** and _should not be used._ But to actually solve this, or at least better understand what's happening, I suggest you run the query without the `FOR JSON` clause and examine how the normal result set is structured.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one potential solution:

```sql
select *
from (
    select json_query((
        select *
        from (
                VALUES  (N'Gallons', N'Fahrenheit', N'Inches')
            ) t (Volume,Temperature,Level)
        for json path, without_array_wrapper, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
        )) as UOM
    ,   (
        select *
        from (
            VALUES  (N'California', N'Sacramento')
            ,   (N'Florida', N'Miami')
            ,   (N'Colorado', N'Denver')
        ) t (State,City)
        for json path
        , INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
        ) as Location
    ) x
for json path, without_array_wrapper
```

Each table gets own for json subquery column which avoids the cross join altogether.

One problem is that when using without_array_wrapper, the json "attribute" is lost, so for this reason i'm doing JSON_QUERY to get it back, without it, it will be handled like a string. Although, in my opinion, you should skip the without_array_wrapper even if table contains one row.

Output:

| JSON_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B |
| --- |
| {"UOM":{"Volume":"Gallons","Temperature":"Fahrenheit","Level":"Inches"},"Location":[{"State":"California","City":"Sacramento"},{"State":"Florida","City":"Miami"},{"State":"Colorado","City":"Denver"}]} |

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Thanks for the clear and explained answer.

Comment: Good answer, +1 from my side!

Comment: Seemes unnecessary to nest it in `JSON_QUERY`, the compiler understands that `FOR JSON` generates valid JSON anyway.

Comment: I don't know @Charlieface, for me without it generated stringified json

Comment: Weird, it seems to depend on whether you use `WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER` https://dbfiddle.uk/yNvrLNuw and https://dbfiddle.uk/Au5dx3qB

Comment: Yeah, that was my finding as well, i added it as a gotcha in the answer. It seems a bit weird indeed, but perhaps SQL Server is too lazy to validate that the resulting json is valid (it wouldn't be in case of > 1 rows) so it removes whatever magic it "tags" json output with so it becomes regular string in need of JSON_QUERY.

Comment: Documented here it's specifically in the case that you specify `WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/solve-common-issues-with-json-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#json-generated-with-the-without_array_wrapper-clause-is-escaped-in-for-json-output Another option is to place the `UOM` subquery on the outside and use explicit paths https://dbfiddle.uk/-Gun20Uz